# Popular question badges awarded multiple times

Tags: discussion, badges

"Popular question badges awarded multiple times", does this mean that the same question will receive a badge every 1000 view? If not I suggest to change the definition of the badge from:

> Asked a question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

to

> Asked a question with 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times but once per question.

Comment: Isn't it apparent from the other two similar badges? I mean the `Notable Question` and the `Famous Question` badges.

Comment: I think it's clear enough as @Ranveer says

Comment: I disagree that the description is ambiguous but if you're going to bring up Popular/Notable/Famous Question what about Favorite/Stellar Question? Plus you could argue that every one-time-only badge should have it explicitly stated that it is one time only as part of the description.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is picky enough:

> Asked a question with at least 1,000 views. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Because next time someone will suggest the badge should be revoked if the question has 1,001 views because it's not exactly 1,000.

I hope it's crystal clear now.

Comment: Come on, was not my intention to open a debate on such finicky basis. As I said above in the comment to Rhoit, and only with the intention to improve the understanding of the "multiple", there are open gaps between 1000 and 2500 and 10000.

Comment: Why would it be revoked? It doesn't say "awarded as long as the question only has 1000 views"... If anything, you would argue that 1001 means the question no longer qualifies for the badge, but you got the badge for when it *was* at 1000 anyway

Answer (score 3):

I guess the description is clear enough. I understood it the first time I read. All such badges which have some specific number of views, or votes, are just a threshold numbers. Reaching that threshold will get you that badge. You can reach that threshold for different question, and hence you can get the badge multiple times.

Let me take an example from real life: If you know about Cricket, there a score *100* runs, or *200* or *300* runs, all count as a single century, and not 2 centuries.

Similarly, there is a "nice question" badge, "great question" badge, that has similar description. Although your suggested description is ok, but it isn't really required IMO.

Comment: May be but still is not clear if before reaching 2500 view you get 2 "popular Question" badges and before reaching "famous question" you get 3 "notable question". Moreover, it should be self explanatory for each badge. I mean, without the need to compare with other badges. –

Comment: @FeliceM It's not about comparison. I guess it is self-explanatory for me. But again, that's really a personal opinion, so I can't deny your understanding. But IMO, that edit is really not required. Still, let's see if some moderators come in with some options.

Comment: @FeliceM: It is perfectly clear as it is. You wouldn't redefine the logic of maths every time someone came along who wasn't clever enough to understand it, would you?

Comment: The biggest communication problem is we do not listen to understand. We listen to reply. (Nishan Panwar quotes)

Answer (score 0):

If your question earns you a 'Popular Question' badge, after that this question will be a candidate for 'Notable Question' badge. That's quite clear. There is no smart reasons for collecting bronze badges for every 1k of views on a single question. So man doesn't need extra explanation.